# What method is called of ionic component when it is opened by router?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic component `recipes`. From another component I can navigate to it using           `this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);` call. 
When call is done component is opened but I also need to update its data. 
I am getting data in `onInit` method but it is not called when `router.navigate` is called.

So my question is what method is called of ionic component when it is opened by router?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any service which is managing the data, you can add thi function in .ts file which will fire every time the data gets changed.

```
/* When the page loading is finished*/
  ngOnInit() {
  }

/* When the data gets changed */
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  }
```